# PathPrefixed Subrouter with individual handlers

Tags: go, mux, gorilla

Given the following ([complete example at Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/TKQ9kgRtoA)):

```
// Collection
root := r.PathPrefix("/widgets/").Subrouter()
root.Methods("POST").Handler(h.Create)

// Individual
object := root.PathPrefix("/{uuid}").Subrouter()
// ~neither: object := root.PathPrefix("/{uuid}").Subrouter() 
object.Methods("GET").Handler(h.Show)
object.Methods("PUT").Handler(h.Replace)
object.Methods("DELETE").Handler(h.Delete)

// Relationships
object.Methods("GET").Path("/foos").Handler(eh.Foos)
object.Methods("GET").Path("/bars").Handler(eh.Bars)
```

I would have expected the following URLs to trigger the respective handlers, but I can't seem to make it work:

```
✔ POST /widgets          => h.Create
✔ GET  /widgets/123      => h.Show    (assumes PathPrefix('/{uuid}'))
✔ GET  /widgets/123/     => h.Show    (required if 'PathPrefix('/{uuid}/')')
✖ GET  /widgets/123/foos => h.Foos    (actually routes h.Show)
✖ GET  /widgets/123/bars => h.Bars    (actually routes h.Show)
```

Unfortunately neither of the last two are apparently routable, they both trigger `h.Show`, can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I might have expected that having an unbounded `{uuid}` (without the trailing slash) could have run-on, ignoring the `/` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I don't even know if this has to do with the Subrouter strict-slash issue which is still open on Github (#31), but to the best of my understanding I did try the alternatives there. (i.e `object.Methods("GET").Path("/").Handler(h.Show)`)

Could the Handler mounted on the `object` root via `Methods()` prevent any further routes matching?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that `gorilla/mux` fires the first matching handler. That's important ***the first matching handler***.

That means that routes logically *under* `/{id}/` are never found, since the routes that would match them are matched first by the parent handler.

Changing the code to the following makes it work as expected:

```
// Collection
root   := r.PathPrefix("/widgets/").Subrouter()
object := root.PathPrefix("/{uuid}").Subrouter()

// Relationships
object.Methods("GET").Path("/foos").Handler(eh.Foos)
object.Methods("GET").Path("/bars").Handler(eh.Bars)

// Individual
root.Methods("POST").Handler(h.Create)
object.Methods("GET").Handler(h.Show)
object.Methods("PUT").Handler(h.Replace)
object.Methods("DELETE").Handler(h.Delete)
```

Then things work perfectly.